# BLOB Image from databasetable to Listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get an image stored as BLOB data in an SQLite database into an Imageview used in a row for a list activity.

This is my code for the two methods I employ to pull regular text data:

```
private void fillData() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String[] from = new String[] { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE };      

int[] to = new int[] { R.id.people_list_name, R.id.people_list_borrowed };

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.people_row, null, from,
        to, 0);

setListAdapter(adapter);

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    BorrowMeContentProvider.distinctSwitch = true;

    String[] projection = { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
        BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

I have another column, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE that I would like to load into my imageView (R.id.pic_of_image). I can't add it to my projection as it cannot be converted to a string. To pull it using a single cursor I would use the code:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = databaseCursor.getBlob(databaseCursor
     .getColumnIndex(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE));
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
     imageByteArray);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
     window.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

As I have done in another part of my program. Can anyone help as to how I would make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your error? and put logcat, so we can help you.

Comment: @Segi I'm really asking how I would modify my fillData to accommodate my images. When I attempt to add the column storing my BLOB data to the projection, I get a data not convertible to String error. I would live my Cursor loader to load the blob data into an image the same way it reads the text in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

> I have another column, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_IMAGE that I would like to
>   load into my imageView (R.id.pic_of_image). I can't add it to my
>   projection as it cannot be converted to a string.

Why do you think so?

If you store images in your database as BLOB data, then you may bravely retrieve them from the DB using their column name in the query projection and after getting the cursor obtain them using `Cursor.getBlob(int)` method.

You also don't need to input gotten byte array to any byte stream to decode it to a bitmap, because `BitmapFactory` has `decodeByteArray(byte[], int, int)` method which allows to decode a byte array to bitmap directly.

The only one thing you should care about is the memory consumption which goes in act when you decode your raw byte arrays to bitmaps.
To work with bitmaps correctly, read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) lessons for better explanation.